# Regex match first group with certain text

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match blocks of text that contain certain text within them. Each block is clearly defined by standard start/end text patterns.

In the below example I want to match steps 1 and 3 from the "step start" to "step end" as they contain the text "database:dev". However my current regex matches step 1 fine, but then matches steps 2 and 3 in a single match. It's probably easier to see with an example here: https://regex101.com/r/56tfOQ/3/

I need to specify that each match can only contain one "step start", but I can't work out how to do that.

The regex I'm currently using is:

```
(?msi)step start.*?database:dev.*?step end
```

An example of the text is:

```
step start
    name:step1
    database:dev1
step end
step start
    name:step2
    database:test1
step end
step start
    name:step3
    database:dev2
step end
step start
    name:step4
    database:test2
step end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a common scenario, you may use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) like `(?:(?!<STOP_PATTERN>).)*?` in between the starting delimiter and some third string that should appear in between delimiters.

You might write your regex as

```
(?si)step start(?:(?!step start).)*?database:dev.*?step end
```

However, it seems your opening delimiter is at the start of a line. Then it makes sense to use

```
(?msi)^step start(?:(?!^step start).)*?database:dev.*?step end
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E1NmPV/1)

Regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `(?msi)` - multiline, dotall and case insensitive modes are on
- `^` - line start (since `m` option is on)
- `step start` - starting delimiter
- `(?:(?!^step start).)*?` - a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) that matches any char, 0+ occurrences/repetitions, as few as possible, that does not start a `step start` char sequence at the start of a line
- `database:dev` - a literal substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `step end` - ending delimiter.

Comment: perfect! thanks. I tried (?msi)step start(?:(?!step start)).*?database:dev.*?step end , at one point. Now I need to work out why the dot being inside the capturing group vs outside makes the difference! Thanks again

Comment: @mjharper There is no capturing group here. The dot in `(?:(?!...).)*?` is part of a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970), it is described well in my other answer. I have added more details.

Comment: sorry - I meant non-capturing group! Will read through your other answer. Thanks again.